# Angular Editable Field Reverting to Original Name After Change

Tags: angularjs, x-editable

I am trying to remotely get a user's name and then have it editable so that it can be saved again.  I am getting the name correctly, but when I try to change it, it reverts back to the old name.

Am I doing something wrong with the defer and resolve?

```
var deferred = $q.defer();
    $http({
            url : '/getuser',
            method : 'GET',
          }).success(function(data) {
             deferred.resolve(data);
          });
         return deferred.promise;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/NfPcH/181/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're assigning the promise directly to your model variable.  So even though in many ways your variable acts like it got the results of the promise it actually instead contains a binding to the promise.

**So your variable keeps getting set to resolved value of the promise during $digest cycles - overwriting your edits.**

So instead of binding your variable to the promise like this:

```
$scope.myUser = getUser();
```

Use the promise's `then` method and assign the results of the promise.  This way `myUser` is initialized to the results of your promise just once instead of being perpetually bound to the promise itself.

```
getUser().then(function(result) {
     $scope.myUser = result;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

For this example, you don't really need to have an explicit `promise`.  `$http` already returns a promise so you really don't need to define a new one.

I've re-arranged the code a bit.  In order to initialize the value, I'm using `ng-init` to call the `getUser()` method.  This then calls `$http` and binds to the `$scope.myUser`.  BTW, I noticed that in only ever enters the `error` callback.

Because promises are async, you must bind to the `$scope` inside the `success` or `error` callback function of `$http`.

The reason it was reverting to the 'old' value was because you were binding directly to the function `getUser()`.  This meant that angular was setting up a `$watch` on the return value of this function.

Here is a [working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/davintryon/h2G45/).

**HTML:**

```
<h4>remote</h4>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="Ctrl" ng-init="init()">
  <a href="#" editable-text="myUser.name" >
    {{ myUser.name || 'not set!' }}
  </a>
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
app.controller('Ctrl', function($scope, $http, $q) {
    $scope.myUser = null;

    $scope.init = function() {

        getUser();
    };

    function getUser() {

            return $http({
                url : 'http://espn.com/images/test-data/public-profile.json',
                method : 'GET',
            })
            .error(function(data) {
                $scope.myUser = {"name":"bobby","age":"21"};
            })
            .success(function(data) {
                console.log(data);
                $scope.myUser = data;
            });

        };
});
```

Comment: chances are is using service for the `$http` in which case returning a promise does make sense....can just return `$http`

Comment: @charlietfl ok, I'll update.  BTW, I was a little surprised that the resolved value bound through to the view.  Does angular unwrap the promise automatically?

Comment: have read in docs it does... still confuses me a bit though. Would have assumed if it shows in page...would already be editable object

Comment: When a promise is assigned to a variable the promise stays bound- thus your issue.  Thus my suggestion to unbind them.

Comment: @KayakDave I don't follow, in the OP fiddle `bobby` was binding through.  Even though `getUser()` was returning a promise.

Comment: It is editable @charliefl  the problem is it keeps being overwritten by the promise during $digest

Comment: @KayakDave does that mean if called `getUser` again elesewhere in app say with different params and thus different response would automatically update scope?

Comment: Yep if the promise results change then the variable changes- when it's assigned as he had. I think that's why this all works the way it does.  They want the variable tightly bound to the promise

Comment: @KayakDave  mmmm...enlightening...thanks. Gives me some new ideas

Comment: It's definitely one of those things that's cool when you know what's happening behind the curtain.

Comment: @KayakDave Wouldn't this be the same for any function return value? Or is there something `special` about promises?

Comment: Looks like another dive into the source for me!  Thanks @KayakDave

Comment: I just realized I spoke out of turn- once an angular promise is resolved it's resolved.  By default you can't change the value.  None the less a variable assigned to the promise keeps being set to the resolved value during digest.  I was remembering this video I just watched which discusses how you can have multiple resolves (so it's possible, but it's not Angular's default behavior):  http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2431-Resolving-An-AngularJS-Deferred-Object-Twice-With-DeferredWithUpdate-js.htm